# Connecting Azure SQL Database with VSCode using service principal

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-sql-database, vscode-extensions, azure-service-principal

I am having issues connecting to a AzureSQL Database/Server using VSCode.
I tried a couple of extensions but non of them seem to support the Active Directory Service Principal authentication.
Has anyone had any success?

I tried using the Azure Tools, which does not support Azure SQL. I tried using the SQL Server (mssql) extension, but as far as I see it does not support that type of authentication, same with SQL Tools by "Matheus Teixeira".

Comment: Could you please provide your sample code and error?

Comment: The SQL Server *mssql) Add in for has support for SQL Authentication, Integrated and Entra Id.

Comment: @ThomA
It supports Entra and SQL Authentication, but it has as far as I saw I cannot connect using a service principal.

Answer (score 0):

***Agreed with @Thom A As far as concern with Connecting Azure SQL Database with VSCode there are only Two methods are supported.***

1. Microsoft Entra Integrated
2. SQL Authentication

Microsoft Entra Integrated and Microsoft Entra Service Principal are not same in integrated authentication we need Microsoft Entra Id user to authenticate.

Microsoft Entra Service Principal  (Active Directory Service Principal authentication) is not supported in **mssql** extension of VSCode

You can connect it with the programming language in VScode using C# as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16)